# Template meta programming inlining

Tags: c++, templates

First look at these templates.

```
struct INIWindows{
    inline int GetInteger(){
        return 100;
    }
};

struct INILinux{
    inline int GetInteger(){
        return 120;
    }
};

template <class Reader>
class SettingsManager : public Reader{

};
```

Edit: Addendum because it was not clear what i was doing.

```
int main(){
    SettingsManager<INIWindows> Settings;
    printf("Integer Reads %i\n",Settings.GetInteger());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Is my understanding correct that this will result in `SettingsManager` having an inline function called get integer that will then be inlined properly by the compiler?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How are related SettingManager and the structures?

Comment: Please don't answer if you don't understand templates. The Structures get passed to settings manager and it becomes the base class of the settings manager.

Comment: I do understand templates. But your question/code is unclear or just wrong. How exactly the structures are "passed" to SettingsManager? How can they become a base class? SettingsManager inherits from Reader.

Comment: @user936509 : your vocabulary is not clear. You mean this: `Settingsmanager<INILinux>`.

Comment: @J.N. i do mean SettingsManager<INIWindows> that is the one that returns 100. The formatting on this page removed the <INIWindows> part of the question it is still there when i edit the question. Weird.

Comment: @user936509 I corrected that for you. If you put the code within the tags between ` it will show up just fine. Have a look at the revision to see what I changed.

Comment: @Bart thanks i decided to reformat it because it seemed to be confusing some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct that this will result in SettingsManager having an inline function called get integer that will then be inlined properly by the compiler.

Yes, your understanding is correct. Your methods are going to be placed in the SettingsManager class, without a virtual dispatch, because the base classes (INIWindows and INILinux) do not have virtual methods.

The `inline` keyword is only a command for the compiler to try to inline the method - nothing else. It is free not to do it.

Comment: True, though i can force inline it. Just wanted to make sure there was no virtual function overhead because its a base class.

Comment: @user936509 You do not have `virtual` keywords in your structures, therefore no virtual dispatch will happen.

Comment: This is not a CRTP, it is close though, a CRTP would be : `template <> class A { };  class B : A<B> { };`

Comment: @J.N. would simulated dynamic binding be a better term?

Comment: No idea what that would be (honestly). I have just compared the pattern with the one on wikipedia.

Comment: CRTP refers to the fact that the base class accepts its derived class as a template, nothing more. The above code has nothing to do with CRTP.

Answer (score 1):

`inline` makes no sense inside a class. If you had defined the functions *outside* a class then it would indicate internal linkage. But in your current code does not serve any purpose whatsoever: *all* functions defined in a class are inline.

For the compiler, `inline` simply means that the name is no visible outside the compilation unit. In this regard, it’s similar to global `static`. Other than that, the compiler is free to perform *function call inlining* any way it wants.

In particular, the optimiser may choose to replace a call by the contents of a function. This is what you want, but it’s (almost completely) unrelated to the `inline` keyword, despite its name.

(By the way, this is unrelated to templates and template metaprogramming.)

Comment: are you saying that your post has nothing to do with templates and template meta programming or that my original question doesn't.

Comment: @user936509 I’m saying  that the question has nothing to do with template metaprogramming. Your code happens to use templates (but calling it metaprogramming is a stretch) but you could have used an example without templates and ask the same question, with the same answer. Templates simply don’t enter the discussion.

Comment: You didn't understand the question then. Read it again. It was about how templates resolve.

Comment: @user936509 No. Your original question was completely unrelated to template resolution. You asked whether the value `100` would be placed at the call site. Whether the class is a template or not is irrelevant for that. Now, you have **removed the question** with your edit. You should fix that.

Comment: I maintain that you failed to comprehend the original question. We obviously disagree so there is no point continuing the conversation.

Comment: @user936509 That is my point: **there is no question**. Your post doesn’t even contain a question mark. Please edit your original post to include a question, then we can discuss. What do you think why your post got downvoted? Obviously I’m not the only one missing a question here. The same goes for the comments under your post.

Comment: now you are being pedantic the final statement is obviously a question regardless of the absence of a question mark. I won't argue with a child. Good day.

Comment: @user936509 Seriously? Several different people tell you they don’t understand the question, *you yourself* claim I don’t understand it, and still you maintain that it’s there in plain sight? So we’re all pedantic idiots and only you are right? Must be ghost rider syndrome.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "`inline` simply means that the name is no visible outside the compilation unit. In this regard, it’s similar to global `static`." That's not quite true, `inline` means "if you see this function defined more than once during linkage, assume they are the same." It's similar to `static` in that you can define multiple functions with the same name without errors, but `static` does so by marking them all as different, while `inline` does so by marking them all the same. (That's why it's UB if you have two `inline` functions with the same name but with differing definitions.)